# System.NotSupportedException:- Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc-5 and entity framework 5:-

```
public bool customerEligableforDeleteAllDelete(long customerid, long cid)
   {
var superadminusers = ourdbset.SecurityRoles
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "super administrator")
    .SecurityRoleUsers
    .Select(a=>a.UserName.ToLower().Trim())
    .ToList();
var superadminusersbygroups = ourdbset.SecurityRoles
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "super administrator")
    .Groups
    .Select(a=>a.ourdbsetUserGroups
            .SelectMany(a1 => a1.UserName.ToLower().Trim()))
    .ToList();
var allsuperadminusers = superadminusers.Union(superadminusersbygroups).ToArray();
var accountCI = entities.AccountCIs
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.CIID == cid);

return ((ourdbset.DeleteAllRequests
        .Where(a => a.CustomerID == customerid
            && !a.Approved
            && allsuperadminusers.Contains(a.RequestedBy.ToLower().Trim())
            && accountCI.ATTRIBUTE_1501.ToLower() == "inactive"))
        .ToList().Count() == allsuperadminusers.Count());
   }
```

but on the return statement, i am getting this error:-

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
```

so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: which line does this bug out on?

Comment: @SimonPrice on the return statement (last line)

Comment: Try moving `accountCI.ATTRIBUTE_1501.ToLower() == "inactive"))` out of the `Where` clause since it is static.

Comment: can you edit the question to include the declaration of the method please so we can see what you are trying to return. It looks to me from the return youre trying to return an bool object

Comment: @SimonPrice ok sure, updated.. thanks

Comment: ok, so when I run into things like this, I take the statement out of the return object and declare it and see what you get as a value on a break point. Is the result what you expect it to be?

Comment: @citronas but this should be part of the where statement

Comment: @test test: No it should not since `accountCI.ATTRIBUTE_1501` does not belong to `x` which is from `DeleteAllRequests`

Comment: thats not the same code as what you have above, but of c1 I would expect you to get an int value, whats the value and type of c1 when you run this?

Comment: @SimonPrice will get the exception

Comment: here is the correct code `var c1 = ourdbset.DeleteAllRequests.Where(a => a.CustomerID == customerid && !a.Approved && allsuperadminusers.Contains(a.RequestedBy.ToLower().Trim())  && accountCI.ATTRIBUTE_1501.ToLower() == "inactive").ToList().Count();`

Comment: @citronas ok remove it and i split my code, so now this statment `var c1 = ourdbset.DeleteAllRequests.Where(a => a.CustomerID == customerid && !a.Approved && allsuperadminusers.Contains(a.RequestedBy.ToLower().Trim())).ToList().Count();` will return the same exception `Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Comment: ok, the only thing now that I can suggest is break it down and build it up until you get the error again. When you get the error again you will be able to target more specifically what the actual issue is and where and then should be able to fix it.

Comment: alternatively, if you can build up the models and objects in a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/ then should be able to help you further

Comment: Database queries are generally case-*in*sensitive. There's no reason to use `ToLower()` all over the code. This can actually harm performance and prevent the database from using any indexes (assuming you use a database).

Comment: Even with strings, you don't need `ToLower`. You can use [String.Equals(string,StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and specify case-*in*sensitive comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
accountCI.ATTRIBUTE_1501.ToLower() == "inactive")
```

First observation, this should not be in your query to db. Do this filter after the query is materialized.

Second, use `.Equals()` instead of `==` when comparing strings.

Third, i have doubts regarding the use of `.Trim()` in the query, i'm not 100% sure of it.

Also, it's not a good practice to return directly the query result. Try to materialize the query in an variable, and then return the variable ( easier to debug, and more clear). For example :

```
var queryResults = ourdbset.DeleteAllRequests
    .Where(a => a.CustomerID == customerid
        && !a.Approved
        && allsuperadminusers.Contains(a.RequestedBy.ToLower().Trim())
    .ToList();

 var count = queryResults.Where(accountCI.ATTRIBUTE_1501.ToLower().Equals("inactive").Count();

 var areEqual = count == allsuperadminusers.Count();
 return areEqual;
```

If this doesn't fix your problem, i would suggest to have a look here: `allsuperadminusers.Contains(a.RequestedBy.ToLower().Trim())`. Make sure `allsuperadminusers` is a list of strings.

Otherwise provide more details in order to help furthermore.